Mattooltip angular mui component is not working properly
I have used mattooltip directive with links in my angular component in my hybrid application.
On hovering the first link, the tooltip position is off and often is empty or content loads after a flicker.
On clicking the link, ngAfterviewinit is called and page content gets updated, the issue is resolved and tooltip works fine.
I am not able to figure out how to prevent this and how to fix this so it works correctly on initial render as well.
 <li class="listItem" *ngFor="let item of items;let index = index; let last = last">
       <a matTooltip="tooltip text"
          (click)="func(); "
           aria-label="link">
           {{item+1}}
        </a>
  </li>


Please create stackblitz and share link

When you do not specify the trackBy function, the ngFor rerenders the loop (for each change detection cycle as per my understanding) which might cause this issue, try using a track by function to solve this.
TS:
trackBy(index, item){
     return index; 
}

HTML:
  <li class="listItem" *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy:trackBy;let index = index; let last = last">
       <a matTooltip="tooltip text"
          (click)="func(); "
           aria-label="link">
           {{item+1}}
        </a>
  </li>


I have tried this, it did not work. I had also created a button outside the ngfor in the component and it was behaving the same way. After a second run of ngafterviewinit, it works fine, but not on the first one.

@RifaFatima please share the stackblitz with the issue replicated for others to check, maybe you are having the component (which contains this code) on another ngFor with the same issue which can be solved by trackby

https://angular-material2-issue-fmejxg.stackblitz.io this is the link, I have replicated the structure of my component but it is working fine here, i do not know what is causing this issue in my application.

@RifaFatima Thank you for the stackblitz copuld you explain the steps to replicate the issue and what to fix

In my application the tooltip is first aligned to the top right corner on first hover and after a delay it comes back to the right position. On second hover it becomes empty and is content loaded after a delay. But if i click the link and somehow trigger an ngafterviewinit again, tooltips seem to work fine. The issue is only present in initial render of component. It is not easily reproducing in stackblitz. Thank you for your patience.
